# Is it possible to manually set the basline for migration with the TFS Integration Platform?

Tags: tfs, tfsintegrationplatform

I had a previous sync using [TFS Integration Platform](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/eb77e739-c98c-4e36-9ead-fa115b27fefe) set up between an open source project we were contributing to, and a private TFS server for our clients that make use of the open source API. Unfortunately, the hardware running this sync failed before back ups were set up.

I've got as far as setting up new hardware, and getting everything installed, but how can I fake it to think that the head revision was v100 on one side, and v18384 on the other? Can this be done by poking around in the Tfs_IntegrationPlatform database directly, if there isn't a UI option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears the only option to do this with the current version of the tools  is by logging an issue with Microsoft Support - they specifically state that it's not something they would recommend doing. In my case, I was able to get the hard disk mounted and alive for long enough to recover the database and restore that.